# Parallel optimisation of string comparison

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm trying to optimise the performance of a string comparison operation on each string key of a dictionary used as a database query cache. The current code looks like:

```
public void Clear(string tableName)
{
    foreach (string key in cache.Keys.Where(key => key.IndexOf(tableName, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0).ToList())
    {
        cache.Remove(key);
    }
}
```

I'm new to using C# parallel features and am wondering what the best way would be to convert this into a parallel operation so that multiple string comparisons can happen 'simultaneously'. The cache can often get quite large so maintenance on it with `Clear()` can get quite costly.

Comment: "The cache can often get quite large " - have you measured you have a performance bottleneck? If not, introducing threads gains nothing and adds complexity.

Comment: If I were you the in the first instance I'd look at optimising my caching approach rather than looking to parallelise the code serving it.

Comment: I've run performance analysers which tell me that 70% of samples were taken within this method, specifically within IndexOf(). Unfortunately I'm constrained to use this caching approach by the existing framework. I wanted to impose an upper limit on the number of elements in cache but that isn't an option either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `cache` object a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) and use `TryRemove` instead of `Remove`.

This will make your cache thread-safe; then, can invoke your current `foreach` loop like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(cache.Keys, key =>
{
    if(key.IndexOf(tableName, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0)
    {
        dynamic value; // just because I don't know your dictionary.
        cache.TryRemove(key, out value);
    }
});
```

Hope that gives you an starting point.

Comment: That's likely to be slower than serial removes without threading.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this but it did perform slower than the original code. I marked it as the answer though, since it did best answer my question, even if it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach can't work well on a `Dictionary<string, Whatever>` because that class isn't thread-safe for multiple writers, so the simultaneous deletes could cause all sorts of problems.

You will therefore have to use a lock to synchronise the removals, which will therefore make the access of the dictionary essentially single-threaded. About the only thing that can be safely done across the threads simultaneously is the comparison in the `Where`.

You could use `ConcurrentDictionary` because its use of striped locks will reduce this impact. It still doesn't seem the best approach though.

If you are building keys from a strings so that testing if the key starts with a sub-key, and if removing the entire subkey is a frequent need, then you could try using a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Whatever>>`. Adding or updating becomes a bit more expensive, but clearing becomes an O(1) removal of just the one value from the higher-level dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I can't afford any extra overhead.

Comment: What sort of extra overhead? There's overhead inherent to your idea of trying to clear in parallel. Where does the overhead of the split lookup impact that this wouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

I've used Dictionaries as caches before and what I've used to do is to do the clean up the cache "on the fly", that is, with each entry I also include its time of inclusion, then anytime an entry is requested I remove the old entries. Performance hit was minimal to me but if needed you could implement a Queue (of `Tuple<DateTime, TKey>` where `TKey` is the type of the keys on your dictionary) as an index to hold these timestamps so you didn't need to iterate over the entire dictionary every time. Anyway, if you're having to think about these issues, it's time to consider using a dedicated caching server. To me, Shared Cache ([http://sharedcache.codeplex.com](http://sharedcache.codeplex.com/)) has been good enough.